# How to use weights for each observation in a classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weights

I have a data set with a number of observations. Based on the results of some preliminary analysis, I have calculated a score for each observation that denotes how "important" each observation is. I want to then train a classifier but I want the classifier to "focus" more on the observations which are more "important", i.e. the ones with the higher scores. Is there a way I can add these scores as "weights" in my classifier somehow? The idea is that the classifier should be able to inherit a little amount of information from the insignificant observations (as these might still have something slightly useful) but the ones with a higher score should be the ones the classifier learns "more" from. I have come across the idea of "weighted classification" but this is assigning weights to observations belonging in imbalanced classes, whereas I am looking at the case of balanced classes, just with some points being more "important" than others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it sounds similar to the imbalanced dataset problem.

**Resample the dataset:** You can sample important observations more often which is very easy to implement without changing your classification model. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812032/using-weightedrandomsampler-in-pytorch/65142119#65142119) of how to implement it in PyTochs using `WeightedRandomSampler`, [CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), or in NumPy using `probability` in [random choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

**Weighted loss:** modify your loss so that it assigns extra weight to each observation. For example, something like this:

```
x = rand(16, 20)
y = randint(2, (16,))
# Try ones(16) here and it will be equivalent to
# regular CrossEntropyLoss
weights = rand(16) # set random weights

net = Linear(20, 2)

def element_weighted_loss(y_hat, y, weights):
    m = LogSoftmax(dim=1)
    criterion = NLLLoss(reduction='none')
    loss = criterion(m(y_hat), y)
    loss = loss * weights
    return loss.sum() / weights.sum()

weighted_loss = element_weighted_loss(net(x), y, weights)
```

[Source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-weight-the-loss/66372/4)

I would argue both methods are similar.

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually did a little bit of searching online and could find the concept of weighing the loss using the obtained scores, which is what I think I need actually. Hadn't thought of the resampling bit but it sounds interesting as well and makes sense intuitively. Thanks a lot for your answer!